# visjs timeline - set initial vertical position of items

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, timeline, vis.js

I'm using `vis-timeline` to render a hundred rows of data. When the component loads, I want to see the rows starting from the beginning: 1, 2, 3, and so on. Instead, by default, `vis-timeline` starts by displaying the end of the list (...97, 98, 99, 100), so that you have to scroll up to get to the top?

There are methods like `setWindow()` for setting the horizontal time frame, but what about the vertical position? I've tried the HTML `scroll()` method, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Normally I would use `orientation: { item: 'top' } }` in the options, but there is a bug that prevents scrolling in that case; it must be set to `'bottom'`.

I've thought about initializing the component with the orientation to `'top'`, then once it displays, setting it to `'bottom'` to allow scrolling, but that seems pretty hacky.

Is there a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a custom ordering function for items (groups as well) using the [`order`](https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/docs/timeline/#Configuration_Options) configuration option:

> Provide a custom sort function to order the items. The order of the
> items is determining the way they are stacked. The function order is
> called with two arguments containing the data of two items to be
> compared.
>
> WARNING: Use with caution. Custom ordering is not suitable for large
> amounts of items. On load, the Timeline will render all items once to
> determine their width and height. Keep the number of items in this
> configuration limited to a maximum of a few hundred items.

See below for an example:

```js
var items = new vis.DataSet();
for (let i=0; i<100; i++) {
  items.add({
    id: i,
    content: 'item ' + i,
    start: new Date(2022, 4, 1),
    end: new Date(2022, 4, 14)
  });
}

var container = document.getElementById('visualization1');
var options = {
  order: function (a, b) {
      return b.id - a.id;
    }
}
var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container);
timeline.setOptions(options);
timeline.setItems(items);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis-timeline-graph2d.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis.min.js" rel="script"></script>
<div id="visualization1"></div>
```